# img that fits into a div

Tags: css, html, background-image, image

I want a background image that automatically fits the div size.

I have several div of the same class, each with different dimensions, is it possible to set the width and the height of the image, exactly to the dimension of the div ?

Do you think is better to use `img` or `background-image`?

P.S I don't know if is it possible to set the dimension of the background image, of course is possible for the tag img, but if I use the tag img the image is separated from the content (it dosen't overlap as a background)

Comment: Are you aiming to maintain the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally if you're going to modify things in this way, I think using img is better.

You can literally just set the height and width of the div if that's what you want.

```
<div class="box"><img src="Path/to/image.png"/></div>
```

and then the CSS would be something like this:

```
.box {
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
}

.box img {
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

That's one way of doing it anyway. You could also set it so that the height is 100% the size of the div, but the width is set to auto so that it scales with it. That way the image won't distort. Like this:

```
.box img {
     height: 300px;
     width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px">
    <img src="image.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>
```

With the background image, you'll not be able to resize the image to the exact dimensions of the div tag.

Comment: I think you should also set `style="display: block;"` on the image just to be sure. Otherwise, some browsers will show varying amount of whitespace around or after the image.

Comment: The problem is that the div can have different size according to the text inside, I can't set 200X200

Comment: @Joe, then you may have to write script to position the image using relative positioning by finding out the left and top of the div and then resize it based on the height and width of the div.